# Import hour, minute, second from csv to timestamp column in external table

Tags: oracle, csv, sqlplus, datetime-format, external-tables

I'm trying to convert a csv data file to an oracle database table. To do so I'm going by an external table as described [here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/art_ext_tabs.htm).

The timestamp in my csv is separated into the date (*yyyy-mm-dd*) on one side and the time (*hh24:mm:ss*) on the other.

My table has 3 columns :

```
create table backup_ext
(
    "user"    NVARCHAR2(20),
    "date"    DATE,
    "hour"    TIMESTAMP
)
```

Here is what the csv looks like :

```
john,2018-05-28,10:17:57
```

I need those three values to be in three separate columns in my table.

The problem I have been encountering is that the user and date appear in the expected format but the hour has date and time in it, like so :

```
user        |date        |hour
----------------------------------------
john         28-MAY-18    01-OCT-19 10.17.57.000000000
```

What I would like is something like this :

```
user        |date        |hour
----------------------------------------
john         28-MAY-18    10.17.57
```

**Other particularities** :

- I want to avoid changing the column type as much as possible since it is used as is in many other areas of the program, and I don't want to break anything
- The table was created like this for use with MSSQL and I have been tasked with adapting it to work with Oracle, this may explain the choice of column types
- I can potentially run a second bit of sql code afterwards to format the column, although I wouldn't know exactly how to do so
- I can only work exclusively with sql statements since this is to be done by a C++ code creating statements and querying the database with said statements

Any help would be greatly appreciated

**Full code :**

```
create table backup_ext
(
    "user"    NVARCHAR2(20),
    "date"    DATE,
    "hour"    TIMESTAMP
)
organization external
(
     type oracle_loader
     default directory csvdir
     access parameters 
     (
         records delimited by newline
         skip 1
         fields terminated by ';' lrtrim
         missing field values are null
         (
             "user",
             "date" date 'yyyy-mm-dd',
             "hour" Char Date_Format Timestamp Mask 'hh24:mi:ss',
         )
     )
     location ('backup.csv')
)
reject limit unlimited;
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the difference between what you are getting and what you want.  A `timestamp` column will always have a day and a time down to subsecond precision.  The client application that queries the timestamp will generally have to convert it to a string in order to display something meaningful to the human.  You can certainly choose to have your client application convert the timestamp to a string that only displays certain components of the timestamp, i.e. `select to_char("hour", 'HH24:MI:SS') from backup_ext`.

Comment: In SQL*Plus, you can control your session's default for converting a timestamp to a string for display by setting your `nls_timestamp_format`, i.e. `alter session set nls_timestamp_format = "HH24.MI.SS"`.  Of course, that only works for your session and if I query the data from a different session I might choose to get a completely different string representation of the same timestamp data.

Answer (score 3):

You say you don't want to change anything, but your'e already migrating it from SQL Server to Oracle...NOW is the time to fix it, or you're going to hate life for the entire time of supporting this application/database going forward.

You only need two columns for your data

```
DROP TABLE BACKUP_EXT;

CREATE TABLE BACKUP_EXT (
       USERNAME    VARCHAR2(20),
       OCCURENCE   DATE
);

INSERT INTO BACKUP_EXT VALUES (
       'john',
       TO_DATE('28-MAY-18 10.17.57', 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS')
);

COMMIT;

SELECT USERNAME "user",
       TO_CHAR(OCCURENCE, 'DD-MON-RR') "date",
       TO_CHAR(OCCURENCE, 'HH.MI.SS') "hour"
  FROM BACKUP_EXT;
```

Execute that...and we get back...

```
Table BACKUP_EXT dropped.


Table BACKUP_EXT created.


1 row inserted.


Commit complete.

user   date        hour       
john    28-MAY-18    10.17.57
```

Use the proper data type -> DATE. A DATE contains a point in time, so this includes a time portion, not just the month, day, year.

Do not use NVARCHAR2 - most modern oracle databases use a Unicode based characterset already, so it's unnecessary, especially for the test data you've provided.

Do not use reserved words like DATE or USER for table or column names - it will cause many more problems than it will solve by forcing it with quotes.

Comment: As much as I like the idea of fixing things now, there are many other applications that depend on querying the hour column specifically since it was built like that with MSSQL and I don't think we can afford either changing everything or creating a specific "Oracle" case for everything

Comment: Then create a view that splits out the time portion, like in the query I show above, name it the name of your SQL table, and all will be good.

Comment: based on your current data model, someone looking at that table could choose the time portion from two different columns, and i'm guessing they're not always going to be the same...so someone is going to write code and get the wrong data. Best to have one source of truth - then build as many views as you want off that singular source.